# Profile name has changed unexpectedly?

Tags: bug, user-accounts, profile-page

Not sure if this is the place to ask, but could not anywhere else I could think to use.

Logged on today to check the stack and posted a comment and saw that it was from "user92109"

Wait, What?!? Thought someone else posted the same comment, but reading it, saw it was the one I posted.

Checked my profile and I see that I am "user92109" now.

I have been on here for 5+ years, I set my profile name a long time ago. How did it suddenly disappear?

Was it deleted for inappropriate content? (Don't think so)  [NJohnny]

Was there a data loss that reverted it?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like it is something specific to this site, because on your profiles elsewhere on the network it still has your name as NJohnny: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAc8v.png

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I checked your user history page (visible only to moderators) and it shows an "edit displayname" event on `2023-05-20 04:09:35Z` where your username was changed from NJohnny to user92109.

Normally, when a user changes their own display name, there is an IP address associated with that change. When a moderator edits a user's display name, if I recall correctly (this doesn't happen often), the moderator's name appears next to the history event. Here, the IP address is `0.0.0.0` and no moderator's name appears.

So I'm as puzzled as you about what happened. It doesn't seem to have been either you or a moderator changing your display name. Let's put it down to the gremlins.

Comment: Ok, as long as it can be traced, so it is not a site bug. I will just change it back. Thanks for checking it.

Comment: Ooops, looks like I have to wait 30 days before I can change it back, (Jun 19)

Comment: I changed it back for you. If it was gremlins, no need for you to be inconvenienced by the 30-day rule.

Comment: Interesting. I've not seen that error before.

Comment: Just checked my Browser history. I was on the site on May 19, then it was 3 days later when I was back on the site. May 22. So I don't think I was online at the site when it happened.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Does anyone at SE staff know about this?

Comment: @Spencer They're probably too busy doing half the moderation work on the network now that [80+ mods and hundreds of other curators are on strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/).

Comment: Could it be a case of someone else using the account may be @NJohnny? Like you forget to log out on a computer and someone played a prank

Comment: @user13267 Nope, Only one using the computer (home laptop)

Comment: @user13267 In any case, from the mod view it doesn't look the same as when a user changes the name themselves.